# How to make LazyColumn reusable

Tags: android, kotlin

When creating a `LazyColumn` layout, is there a way to modify the items source (i.e. `Array<Starters>`) to something else so that I can reuse my `LazyColumn` for a different set of items from a different array?

```
@Composable
fun MyLazyColumn(lazyItems: Array<Starters>,
                  onClickItem: (Starters) -> Unit
) {
    LazyColumn() {
        items(lazyItems) { choice -> Row() { Text(text = stringResource(id = choice.textResId)) } }
    }
}

Scaffold(
    content = {
        MyLazyColumn(lazyItems = arrayOf(Starters.Canapes,...), onClickItem = startersClickListner)
    }
)
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure but Try generic type and check type before passing your collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generic lazyColumn by giving the opportunity for the caller to use the item composable that he want with a @Composable function callback.

Exemple :

```kotlin
@Composable
fun <T> MyLazyColumn(
    lazyItems: Array<T>,
    onClickItem: (T) -> Unit,
    item: @Composable RowScope.(item: T) -> Unit,
) {
    LazyColumn() {
        items(lazyItems) { choice ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = { onClickItem(choice) })
            ) {
                item(choice)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your scaffold :

```kotlin
    Scaffold(
        content = {
            MyLazyColumn<Starters>(
                lazyItems = arrayOf(Starters.Canapes, ...),
                onClickItem = startersClickListner
            ) {
                Text(text = stringResource(it.textResId) )
            }
        }
    )
```

If you want to use a custom key you can add another function parameter

```kotlin
@Composable
fun <T> MyLazyColumn(
    lazyItems: Array<T>,
    onClickItem: (T) -> Unit,
    key: ((item: T) -> Any)? = null,
    item: @Composable RowScope.(item: T) -> Unit
) {
    LazyColumn() {
        items(
            items = lazyItems,
            key = key
        ) { choice ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = { onClickItem(choice) })
            ) {
                item(choice)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And on the caller side, you can use it like this

```kotlin
data class Foo(
    val id: Int
)

MyLazyColumn(
        lazyItems = arrayOf(
            Foo(1), Foo(2)
        ),
        key = {
            it.id
        },
        onClickItem = {
            // ...
        }
    ) {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Don't you need to use keys with LazyColumn? How can you get the id value from the generic `T`? `T.id` won't work and will throw an Unresolved reference error.

Comment: Firstly, You don't necessarily need to use a key inside a LazyColumn. According to documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope#items(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2 by default it will use the position of the item as key.

Secondly, If you want to have less abstraction you can replace T by any type you want and when you will use the composable, the item will need to extend the type you choosed

Comment: I edited my answer to show an example on how to define a custom key

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I'm assuming that you're passing back the item T back to the caller via the key lambda, but how are you then setting the the `id` key value at the calling site?

Comment: I Updated my answer. the key function parameter allow you on caller side to use any attributes of the class provided. Here I created a Foo data class which has an id attributes that I can use in the key function parameter

Comment: Great. Just one more thing. When you read the `id` value at the calling site in the lambda callback via `it.id`, is it implicitly setting the item key in the `LazyColumn` in the `MyLazyColumn` composable?

Comment: Exactly because the function is used by the items key lambda so you are setting it directly on the LazyColumn

Comment: I want to make the custom `LazyColumn` composable even more reusable by specifying a more generic type for `lazyItems` with `Collection<T>` so that we can pass in any collection type for the items like `List<T>`, `Set<T>`, or `Map<T>`. But specifying `Collection<T>` throws an error in the `items` DSL method stating it requires `Int` but found `Collection<T>`. How can I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: The issue here is that you forgot the following import : import androidx.paging.compose.items

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Dinamots is probably the most "Compose" way to go about it. However, if all the things you want to give to the column have a common parent or interface they implement, you can do something like this to get a little more code reuse.

```kotlin
interface Choice {
    val textResId: Int
}

@Composable
fun <T : Choice> ChoiceColumn(
    choices: Array<T>,
    onChoiceClick: ((T) -> Unit) = { }
) {
    BasicLazyColumn(choices, onChoiceClick) {
        Text(stringResource(it.textResId))
    }
}

@Composable
fun <T> BasicLazyColumn(
    choices: Array<T>,
    onItemClick: ((T) -> Unit) = { },
    itemBuilder: @Composable LazyItemScope.(item: T) -> Unit
) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(choices) { choice ->
            Row(Modifier.clickable {
                onItemClick(choice)
            }) {
                itemBuilder(choice)
            }
        }
    }
}
```