# How to use item id values as keys with generics in LazyColumn?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72500715/10259491), we can make a reusable `LazyColumn` composable by using generics. But, if we need to use the item's `id` value as the key, using `T.id` throws an `unresolved reference` error. How can we specify the `id` for key values if using generics in the `LazyColumn`?